# actionscript 3 take text from another MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movieclip called "auto", inside it I have a text called "title" and a movieclip "info". 
Into info I have a script in as3 and I want to take the title form the superior movieclip called auto.
Movieclip info is inside the movieclip.
This is my code inside info but doesn't work

```
trace(auto.title.text)
```

Comment: I can't see any errors because is into a comlicated swf structured link into a database online and I can only test my swf in my  site online I can't have any debug and this is really bad I know but isn't mine the project

Comment: But with that code in the compilator error I have this error: "Access at not defined property with reference at static Class type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you added to script to info, so your code is looking for a property or clip inside info called "auto".  But auto is not inside info.

instead, try `trace(info.parent.title.text);`